# CodeBlocks MinGW on XP noob. Is it possible to overwrite the same exe every time I compile? Further explanation inside

Tags: c, compiler-construction, ide, mingw, codeblocks

I have looked through both the CodeBlocks and MinGW FAQ and wiki to no avail. As stated above I am a noob.

I want CodeBlocks to act like a Unix compiler in that it overwrites a single output file every time it compiles unless told to do otherwise.

In Unix:
[cc example.c] -> [a.out], [cc example2.c] -> [a.out]. If I want to save the output file from being overwritten i just [cc -o newname example3.c] - [newname.out].

If this is possible with CodeBlocks/MinGW on XP I'd like to know how to do it. If not I would appreciate recommendations for another GUI compiler/IDE that could. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: make sure the exe is not already running. code::blocks requires you to "Press any key" to exit the application launched from it :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I want CodeBlocks to act like a Unix
>   compiler in that it overwrites..

First of all, C::B isn't a compiler -- it's an IDE. Saying you want C::B to act like a compiler makes no more sense then saying you want vim, emacs, or visual studio to 'act' like a compiler.

Second, you change the name of the final executable by right-clicking a project in your workspace. Goto properties->Build targets tab->select which build target you want to change. On the right side of this you'll see Output filename. Enter the executable filename the linker should output here. Alternatively, you can just navigate to the location of your existing executable and just rename it to something else.

And thirdly, chances are you're not even going to be checking back on this site so I'm probably just wasting my time giving an answer to your post.